# Стоит ли при Деплое подключить Bootstrap локально?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap, deploy

Извините если мой вопрос будет глупым, я не смог нагуглить эту информацию, поэтому решил задать вопрос здесь. Я только начинаю свой путь

Есть ли смысл перед деплоем подключить Bootstrap к проекту локально (скачать файлы фрейморвка и закинуть нужные файлы в проект)? Или можно оставить с подключением через ссылку?

Какие + и - у обоих вариантов подключения бутстрапа? Какой из них лучше на практике?

Comment: ну когда выйдет какая-то обнова, и у тебя сломается верстка , узнаешь про минусы с:

Comment: Окей, подключу-ка лучше локально :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбор что лучше или хуже оставлю на вас т.к. мне кажется это немного холиварная тема;)

Минусы подключить сторонний bootstrap

1. Как справедливо заметил Вадим, если вдруг библиотека обновится, соответственно обновится твоя подключенная библиотека (это случится при условии если допустим ты всегда подключаешь последнею версию, а не фиксированную)
2. Т.к. ты подключаешь со стороннего сервиса, то есть вероятность, что тот cdn с которого подключаешь (загорится, заблокирует РКН, просто внезапно отвалится сегмент интернета по не завищим от тебя причинам) т.е. ты не контролируешь доступ к этому cdn, а даешь на откуп сторонним людям

Плюсы подключить сторонний bootstrap

1. С тебя снимается головная боль по поводу организации доступа к статике т.е. тебе не надо беспокоится с каким откликом отдается твоя статика условному Джону из Канады cdn распределение берут на себя
2. Ну соответственно ты экономишь на хостинге т.к. часть трафика идёт к другому хосту

Минусы иметь свой bootstrap

1. С тебя не снимается головная боль по  поводу организации доступа к статике т.е. тебе надо беспокоится с каким откликом отдается твоя статика условному Джону из Канады придёт
2. Распределение нагрузки твой враг

Плюсы иметь свой bootstrap

1. Ты не зависишь от сторонних сервисов или ещё чего то, ты сам несёшь ответственность
2. Контроль версии, ты можешь сам выбирать, когда обновлять фронт и надо ли

p.s. тут приведено исключительно моё мнение и вероятно найдётся человек более знающий, который сможет поправить мой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Буду иметь в виду